# Available tokens in the Filter Section of Views

Tags: views, tokens

Are any tokens(as nid) available in the FILTER CRITERIA of Views (see pic bellow). For example I can sort out all nodes with greater than the current NID...

[image]

Comment: have you tried to use `contextual filters`?

Comment: been thinking how to do it with contextual filters but haven't figured it out yet? any advise ? :)

Comment: you want to exclude the current node or keep it?

Comment: exclude the current and show up 3 or 4 with the same type and greater nid

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any way in the Views UI to do this, but you certainly can with a hook:

```
function YOURMODULE_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {

  if ($view->name=='THE_VIEW_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_FOR' && ($node=menu_get_object())) {

    $filters = $view->display_handler->get_option('filters');

    $filters['nid']['value']['value'] = $node->nid;

    $view->display_handler->override_option('filters', $filters);

  }

}
```

which would set the value in the node nid filter to that of the node nid the View is displayed on.